# How to randomly change ties in a bipartite network without creating ties within the same level

Tags: r, igraph

I have an undirected bipartite network where I want to randomly switch ties around while still maintaining the same degree distribution.

Working in igraph, I've used the rewire() and keeping_degseq() functions to randomly switch edges between nodes as shown in the code below. However, this results in edges being created between nodes that are in the same mode. For this sample network, nodes 1 through 10 are in one mode, and nodes 11-14 are in another mode.

```
library(igraph)
set.seed(1)

b <- sample_bipartite(10,4,type = "gnp", p = 0.5)
b2 <- rewire(b, keeping_degseq(niter = 100))
b2
```

The resulting edges are:

> [1]  1--13  3--11  5--11  3-- 6  7--12  1--11  9--12  9--11  7--14  8--13 12--13  4-- 6 13--14 11--14 10--11  1--12  2--10  3--14  5--14  6--14 12--14
>     8--14  6-- 9 10--14

Edges such as 12--13, 3--6, and 13--14 are between nodes in the same mode, which is a property of the original network that I want to preserve in this simulation.

Is there a different function that better serves my purpose? Is there a way to tell the rewire() function not create edges between nodes in the same mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of doing something with edges, we may permute the vertices:

```
set.seed(1)
b1 <- sample_bipartite(10,4,type = "gnp", p = 0.5)
table(degree(b1))
# 1 2 3 4 5 6 
# 4 3 2 2 2 1 

(b2 <- permute(b1, c(sample(1:10), sample(11:14))))
# IGRAPH cf35948 U--B 14 20 -- Bipartite Gnp random graph
# + attr: name (g/c), p (g/n), type (v/l)
# + edges from cf35948:
#  [1]  5--14  4--14  9--14  3--14  5--11  8--11  4--11  7--11 10--11  5--13  8--13  6--13
# [13]  7--13  3--13 10--13  5--12  4--12  2--12  1--12 10--12
table(degree(b2))
# 1 2 3 4 5 6 
# 4 3 2 2 2 1
```

This approach is also easily generalizable to, say, multiple communities. It all depends on the blocks of shuffled vertex indices in the second argument of `permute`. Instead of thinking about shuffling, an easy way to see why this works is to think that we only switch around the names of the vertices.

Comment: I really like this idea. Another approach could be to use the `birewire.rewire.bipartite` function from the `BiRewire` package.

Comment: Follow up question: how does the syntax differ if the nodes from the different modes have different names. For example, what if the nodes from one mode were in character form (e.g. "11", "12", "13", "14" instead of 11,12,13,14)?

Comment: @jcr, the second argument of `permute` should be integers, from 1 to `vcount(g)`. The meaning of this vector is: the order of old vertices in the new graph. So, `c(3,1,2)` in the new graph first would put the third vertex, then the first one, and the the second one (in the initial graph). If vertices are named, then perhaps `permute` is not what you want since, if initially A is connected to B, C, D, after the permutation the same would be true, just A, B, C, D would correspond to different rows/columns in the adjacency matrix...

Comment: ... If you want to also mix up the neighbours of each vertex, you may want `V(g)$name <- sample(V(g)$name)` (or a certain variation of it, according to modes).

Comment: Wouldn't that just randomize the names completely? Is there way to tie the vertex ID to the name so that when the graph is permuted the names are shuffled with the vertices?

Comment: @jcr, yes, `V(g)$name <- sample(V(g)$name)` would shuffle the names of the rows and columns of the adjacency matrix, but the matrix entries would remain the same. It would mean that vertex A afterwards may have a different number of friends. Doing what my answer proposes permutes the rows and columns of the adjacency matrix, but A will have the same friends in both cases, so in this case the vertex ID is tied to the name, I believe...

Comment: ...Also I see that my explanation of `c(3,1,2)` above is wrong. Say that initially the names are `c("A", "B", "C")`. Then `c(3,1,2)` permutation would but the names to `c("B", "C", "A")`.